# Crop bottom HTML5 video

Tags: html5-video, shopify

I have a shopify shop where I want to have a video banner.
I managed to set it up like the code below.

It shows up on the site and works well but I want to reduce the height of the video because it is really big. But when I adjust the height and set the video height to 75% then the bottom part of the video is not showing. It is just cut off the video.

Can I adjust the height while the video is showing the full video but rescaled?

I tried a lot of things found on internet but none worked for me. Can someone help me please?

Thanks.

Best regards,

Kevin

```
Liquid/HTML

{% if template.name == "index" %}
<div class="top2">
    <div class="wrapper2">
        <video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
            <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0093/6552/0444/files/Smilezz.Promovideo.2019.Bannervideo2.1080p.mp4?4182" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
</div>  
{% endif %} 

CSS

.top2 {
        padding-bottom: 56.25%;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
}

.wrapper2 {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 200%;
        transform: translateY(-35.95%);
    margin-bottom: -200px;
    font-size: 0;
}

video {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width:100%;
        height: 85%;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The video simply needs to keep aspect ratio, otherwise the video will be cutted either vertically or horizontally.

The best approach is to control the width of video, and the height will scale automatically

**Your edited CSS:**

```
  .top2 {
    display: block;
    /* example width - can use '%' as well */
    width: 300px;
  }

  .wrapper2 {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
  }

  video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not working. If I use your code I get a little video on the left of the page. When I set top2 width to 100% to get the video in fullwidth then the video is way to big.